# getting all 1st sub-folders that contain a specific file nodejs

Tags: node.js, file, directory

I'm looking to get an object that will contain all the 1st sub-folders only that contain a specific file.

for example:

```
<cwd>
|a
|-aa
|-ab
|-this.file
|b
|-other.file
|c
|-cc
|--this.file
|d
|-this.file
```

here i'd like the get something like

```
["a","d"]
```

or with the full path.

is anything like this been done before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely something like this have been done before, and it is quite simple.

What you should do is iterate over the current folder sub-directories, and check if the file you want exists there - if it does save the current sub-folder name.

I recommend you use node's native module for handling files by importing it as so

`let fs = require('fs')`

it has a few functions that might be helpful to you, such as:

`fs.readdir()` or `fs.readdirSync()` which gives you the content of the folder.

`fs.stat(path,{withFileTypes: true})` or `fs.statSync(path,{withFileTypes: true})` which gives you information about an entry, and can help you determine if an entry is a file or a dir. (the withFileTypes option makes this function return a Dirent object that has that data).

Reference to the official Node.js documentation: [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks, I'm was able to do it with the sync functions, for some reason I couldn't do it with the  `{withFileTypes: true}` option in the async functions